# Codeblock File Explorer doesn't show files

Tags: codeblocks

In the tab Files of my CodeBlocks I can't see files. The File Explorer shows me only the directory tree.

To load a .cpp file I need to go in my workspace directory, then I can chose to open it in C::B. The file is loaded in the IDE but I can't see it in the File Explorer.

If I create a new file by righ click on the direcoty in the IDE, I don't see the file there, but I will find the file in my workspace directory in the disk.

Answer (score 2):

The File Manager plugin displays a tree-view of your computer's filesystem in the **Files** tab,
in which you can navigate to any directory or file in the usual way.

It's principal purpose is to let you browse and view files in the filesystem that are *not* in your project(s). 
To browse, open and edit files that *are* in your project(s), use the **Projects** tab, where you
can navigate to any project in the workspace, and any file in any of the projects.

If you create a new file in the **Files** tab, all you have done is create a file
in the filesystem. If you want to add it to your project, right-click on it and select
**Add to active project...**. Then you will see it in the **Projects** view. And if you
do this, it would be advisable to create the file *in your project's directory*.

The usual way to add a file to your project and place it in the project directory
by default is to select **File** -> **New** from the menu-bar.

Comment: I don't need to create C++ project, I need to run very simple C++ programs, each one with the main and contained in a single file. The problem is that my .cup files exist in my file system but they are no shown in C::B. I can navigate my directory tree but no files are shown.